# Npm Eroor : I can't install npm with @

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-package

Hello im trying to download this npm : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer

but it give me this error

```
npm install @bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer
At line:1 char:13
+ npm install @bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer
+             ~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@bam' can be used only as an argument to a  
command. To reference variables in an expression use '$bam'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
```

I have tried everything, i have updated npm and rezet nodes-modules but still i have this error

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've already solved the problem, but I'll leave it here in case anyone needs it.

Just surround the package name with double quotes:

```bash
npm install "@bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer"
```